# Importing moment js in aurelia gives script error

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs, aurelia

I tried to use value converter in aurelia to format my date with data-binding as shown here: https://jdanyow.github.io/aurelia-converters-sample/
For that I did 
`npm install moment --save`
And created a date-format.js with the same content as in the link i.e.

```
import moment from 'moment';

export class DateFormatValueConverter {
      toView(value) {
         return moment(value).format('M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss a');
  }
}
```

When I do
 `<require from="date-format"></require>`

```
<div repeat.for="object of objects">
    <span>${object.startDate | dateFormat} </span>
</div>
```

I get Script error for "date-format".

On the momentjs website, it suggests setting 
`"allowSyntheticDefaultImports":  true`.
That is set as well. What am I missing?

**Update:**

I have checked the question it is marked as a duplicate of. I have implemented the suggested answer `import * as moment from 'moment'`, and also tried autoinjects. It works when I do import on viewmodel. But when I do `<require from='date-format'></require>` on html side, after having a value converter in date-format.js as above, I get the error below, and hence I cannot use `<span>${object.startDate | dateFormat}</span>` on my view.

ERROR [app-router] 
Error
**stackCleaned**: true
columnNumber: 17
fileName: "http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js"
lineNumber: 4414
message: "Script error for \"date-format\"\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror"
originalError: error
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
explicitOriginalTarget: 
isTrusted: true
originalTarget: 
target: 
timeStamp: 361.99413968425523

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: @Timo It's a generic script error. 

Error: Script error for "date-format"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    makeError@http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:4414:17
    onScriptError@http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:5984:36

Comment: You should always include the full error message, see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough

Comment: @JessedeBruijne Thank you. I'm new in posting questions, will follow the guidelines. I have updated my question with error message.  I've checked the other question it is identified as a duplicate of, I have used 'import * as moment from moment' as suggested. It doesn't solve my problem of getting error when I do <require from="date-format"> on html side.

Comment: your error just feels like your path is incorrect. try adding a path like `../resources/value-converters/date-format`

Comment: @JessedeBruijne no...that was the first thing I checked. Other components in the same location are being referenced fine. I tried moving the date-format.js to different locations as well.

Comment: @JessedeBruijne It simply worked by changing extension of date-format from js to ts. Pretty sure I had tried that earlier, but well....Thanks for your inputs.